# How to add different applications to a same CDF

Tags: cdf-format, deployment

Let say I have a multiple small application utilities, how can I add them to a same CDF with a table of content (or navigation panel) on the left of the CDF, and if I want to open one application, I only need to scroll down to the application navigator on the left, click, and the application run ? (Similar to what appears in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEbo-QAIWqc)

Answer (score 1):

One way to have many different small applications in the same file is to have multiple Manipulates. For instance, a file with two cells:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[f x], {x, -3, 3}], {f, 1, 10}]

Manipulate[Plot[Cos[g x], {x, -3, 3}], {g, 1, 10}]
```

and then saved as CDF works fine. You can hide/view the different manipulates by double clicking on the brackets on the right hand side of the cells. There are also little triangles to the left of the word Manipulate that open/close the displays.